# HTML Dropdown Form with links in the dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery

I currently have 2 links on the page, http://test.medialayer.net/, which I'd like to put in an html dropdown, current code below, any anchor with the class ezjax will load the linked page into the div, ezjax content.

```
<div id="homePagePropertySearchBox">
    <a class="ezjax" href="../../../searchForms/searchOne.html">Search One</a>
    <a class="ezjax" href="../../../searchForms/searchTwo.html">Search Two</a>
    <div id="ezjax_content"> 
        <!-- THIS IS THE CONTAINER WHERE THE CONTENT WILL BE LOADED --> 
    </div>
</div>
```

I found this code below which is going the direction I want to go, except onchange I want it to just open my link in the ezjax content div

```
<form action="../">
<select onchange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_top')">
    <option value="">Choose a destination...</option>
    <option value="http://www.yahoo.com/">YAHOO</option>
    <option value="http://www.google.com/">GOOGLE</option>
    <option value="http://www.altavista.com/">ALTAVISTA</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Once again my thanks to all those who take a look.
Chuck

For reference here is the rest of the code that makes the loading happen.

on page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
$('.ezjax').ezjax({ 
container: '#ezjax_content',
initial: '../../../searchForms/searchOne.html',
effect: 'slide',
easing: 'easeOutBounce',
bind: 'a'
});
```

linked js file

```
jQuery.fn.ezjax = function(o) {

  obj = jQuery(this).attr('class'); 

  // Defaults
  var o = jQuery.extend( {
    container: '#ezjax_content',
    initial: null,
    effect: null,
    speed: 'normal',
    easing: null,
    bind: '.'+obj
  },o);

  // Load initial

    if(o.initial!=null){
        jQuery(o.container).load(o.initial,function(){
        bind();
});
}

  // Re-bind for any links internal to the content

function bind(){
    jQuery(o.container+' '+o.bind).ezjax({
        container: o.container,
        initial: null,
        effect: o.effect,
        speed: o.speed,
        easing: o.easing
    });
}

  // Main functionality

  return this.each(function() {

jQuery(this).click(function(){
    var url = jQuery(this).attr('href');

    // Check for transition effect

    if (o.effect != null) {

        // Run effect
        switch(o.effect){

            // Slide
            case 'slide':
            jQuery(o.container).animate({height:"0px"}, o.speed, function(){
                jQuery(o.container).css('overflow','hidden'); // Fix glitchies
                jQuery(o.container).load(url, function(){
                    jQuery(o.container).animate({
                        height: jQuery(o.container).children().height() + 20
                    },o.speed,o.easing,function(){
                        jQuery(o.container).css('overflow','visible'); // Undo glitchy fix
                    });
                    bind();
                });
            });
            break;

            // Fade
            case 'fade':
            jQuery(o.container).animate({ opacity: 0.0 }, o.speed, function(){
                jQuery(o.container).load(url, function(){
                    jQuery(o.container).animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, o.speed);
                    bind();
                });
            });
            break;
        }

    }
    else {
        // Standard load (no effect)
        jQuery(o.container).load(url,function(){
            bind();
        });
    }

    // Keeps the href from firing
    return false;

});

  });

};
    });
</script>
```

Comment: could you put your code on jsfiddle?

Comment: Here is the link, http://jsfiddle.net/cwilson/WNR3x/  it's not working the same on jsfiddle as it does on my site, http://test.medialayer.net/ I'll keep messing with it to see if I can get it working the same.

Comment: You don't need to wrap the JS in `<script>` tags on JS Fiddle, so long as it's in the JS panel it'll be parsed properly. :)

Comment: Thanks David, tonight was the first time I've come across JSFiddle, looks awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there is a better way to do it (by rebinding the event?), but I got this to work with a small edit to the EZJax plugin.

Changes are

- Trigger Ajax event on change rather than on click as now
- Use the dropdown's value instead of
  link's href

So altering these lines

```
jQuery(this).click(function(){
    var url = jQuery(this).attr('href');
```

to this

```
jQuery(this).change(function(){
    var url = jQuery(this).val();
```

seems to work.

Obviously you need to give the select values as in your example and the class `.ezjax`.

Hope it works for you too. :)

Comment: That appears as if it will work, it just keeps opening in new window instead of the ezjax_content div, and I think the culprit for getting it to work is when I do select onchange it's set to window.open, I tried changing it to window.(a variety of things) I just don't know what to change it to?

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it clearer. As the change event is now handled by the EZJax plugin, you don't need to set onchange in the select. So just <select class="ezjax"><option ...></select>